# change background of textview for listview item get focused

Tags: android, listview

i have this listview [image]

each listview item has a textview that have background , i want to change the background of the textview of listview item  get focused .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#selector-element).
**Edit:**
 Use selector drawable as a background for ListView elements, or specify a [android:listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector) for a ListView

Answer (score 0):

you have change background color in onfocusChangeListener. Try with following code,

```
livView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
                if(hasFocus){
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(bg_color);
                }
            }
        });
```